# atol yields same results for different strings

Tags: c, hash, std, hash-function

As suggested in the comments of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369314/hash-function-for-phone-numbers) question, I am using as a hash function this:

```
atol(phone) % buckets
```

However, I got the same exact result from `atol()` for all my phone numbers! I removed the first two digits (they are the same for all the numbers in my case) and got different results (of course collisions were detected..).

Why this happened?

Check the output of this:

```
printf("%s %ld %ld %s %ld %d %ld\n", str, atol(str), atol(str) % N,
         phone, atol(phone), N, atol(phone) % N);
```

Just some instances:

```
48614858 48614858 58 6948614858 2147483647 200 47
61468264 61468264 64 6961468264 2147483647 200 47
54079694 54079694 94 6954079694 2147483647 200 47
48370923 48370923 123 6948370923 2147483647 200 47
52746354 52746354 154 6952746354 2147483647 200 47
```

Meta-question: If a better approach can be suggested to get a better hash function, I am still open in changing my code.

EDIT:

`strtol()` gives same results.

Comment: any specific reason for not using `strtol()`?

Comment: I thought about that, but the comments suggested `atol()`. Let me take a look.

Comment: to fit `6948614858`, you may need `strtoll()` or `atoll()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's because the provided phone number is too big to fit in an integer, thus, `atol()` can not convert the string well, please check `errno` after calling `atol()` to make sure there's no error occurs during conversion.
in this case, you can try to use function `atoll()` to convert the phone number, function `atoll()` can fit a long long integer.