# Why using powers of 2 as the hash size makes a hash table considerably worse than using primes?

Tags: math, hash, language-agnostic, hashtable, bit-manipulation

I'm implementing a hash table that is supposed to store pairs of 32-bit values. Considering my elements are fixed size, I'm using a very simple hashing function:

```
hash(a,b) = asUint64(a) + (asUint64(b) << 32)
```

With that, I get the index of an element in a hash table (that is, its corresponding bucket) with:

```
index(a,b) = hash(a,b) % hash_size
```

Where hash_size is the number of entries/buckets on my table. I've realized, though, that I could speed up this implementation a little bit if I replaced the "modulus" operator by a [bitwise `mod of 2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072665/bitwise-and-in-place-of-modulus-operator), by fixing hash_size as a power of 2. **Except, when I do that, most of my pairs end up on the first bucket!** Why is that happening?

Comment: if you mod by power of 2, you are destroying a lot of the data that is present in `b`, and possibly `a`.

Comment: I guess that sounds reasonable, but why?

Comment: It is odd that you say most of your pairs end up on the first bucket. I expect more collisions with this scheme, but I suspect your case is more due the distribution of your data.

Comment: Rehash your hash with [MurmurHash3](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3) avalanche function and continue using power of 2 size.

Comment: Also you can find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26353689/648955) useful

Comment: Read about [Bezout Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your data is not evenly distributed in `a`. Consider the concatenation of `a` and `b` as your hash code:

```
b31b30...b1b0a31a30...a1a0, where ai, bi is the ith bit of a,b
```

Suppose you have a table with a million entries, your hash index is then

```
a9a8...a1a0 (as an integer)
```

Worse, suppose `a` only ever ranges from 1 to 100. Then you have even less dependence on the higher order bits of `a`.

As you can see, if your hash table doesn't have at least 4 billion entries, your hashcode has no dependence on b at all, and `hash(x, a)` will collide for all `x`.

Comment: That is enlightening, thanks. This is not on the scope of the question so feel free not to answer it, but what hashing function would you recommend on this case?